# Time series question - prove by induction

Tags: time-series

Can anyone help with this question..

Consider the process {X(1), X(2), ...} satisfying

$X(t)=αX(t−1)+ε(t)$ for all integers $t≥2$, (1)

where the random variable $X(1)$ satisfies $E(X(1)) = 0$ and has finite variance.

Also suppose that:

(i) For all integers $t ≥ 2$, $ε(t)$ and $(X(t−1),...,X(1))(X(t−1),...,X(1))$ are independent.

(ii) The ε(t) are independent and identically distributed with $E(ε(t))=0$ and $E(ε^2(t))=σ^2>0$.

$X(t)=α^{t−1}X(1)+ε(t)+αε(t−1)+⋅⋅⋅+α^{t−2}ε(2)$    (2)

(a) Check that the formula (2) is true for $t = 2$.

(b) Suppose that the formula (2) is true for given $t ≥ 2$. Using (1) prove that (2) is true for t replaced by t + 1

What I started with for (a) was:

$αX(t−1)+ε(t)=α^{t−1}X(1)+ε(t)+αε(t−1)+⋅⋅⋅+α^{t−2}ε(2)$

= $αX(2−1)+ε(2)=α^{2−1}X(1)+ε(2)+αε(2−1)+⋅⋅⋅+α^{2−2}ε(2)$

= $αX(1)+ε(2)=α^{1}X(1)+ε(2)+αε(1)+⋅⋅⋅+α^{0}ε(2)$
but i don't know where to go from there (or if it's correct)...

What I started with for (b) was:

subbed t+1 into t

$αX(t+1−1)+ε(t+1)=α^{t+1−1}X(1)+ε(t+1)+αε(t+1−1)+⋅⋅⋅+α^{t+1−2}ε(2)$

= $αX(t)+ε(t+1)=α^{t}X(1)+ε(t+1)+αε(t)+⋅⋅⋅+α^{t-1}ε(2)$

and also didn't know where to go from there?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a [self-study] tag.

First of all there is sort of a mistake in formula (2). It should be written like this:

$X(t)= \alpha^{t−1} X(1) + \sum_{i=2}^t \alpha^{t-i} \epsilon (i)$

I hope you are ok with [summation notation](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/summation.html). If not let me know.

So for a) what you do is this:

$X(2) = \alpha X(1) + \epsilon(2)$. 
This we know is true since this formula is given to us in your description of the time series process. Right?

Now notice, formula (2) (written the way I wrote it) for $t=2$ looks like this:

$X(2)= \alpha^{1} X(1) + \sum_{i=2}^2 \alpha^{t-i} \epsilon (i) = \alpha^{1} X(1) +  \alpha^{0} \epsilon (2)$. This is equal to what we said we know is true for $X(2)$ up above. Check! we proved part a).

Now for b)

We are assuming that formula (2) is true for some arbitrary $t$ and we need to show it is true for $t+1$. We does that mean that it is true for $t$ ?
Let's write the formula:

We are assuming that $X(t) = \alpha^{t−1} X(1) + \sum_{i=2}^t \alpha^{t-i} \epsilon (i)$.

Now what do we know about $X(t+1)$? we know its relationship to $X(t)$ from the description of the process of the time series. well from here you should think a bit and I can help further if you need.